# Strange error in python3

Tags: python, if-statement

I did an easy management program but looks like I have a strange error. Here is my code:

```
scelta = 0
print("Welcome in the program 'Be in time at home'")
bus = input("Which bus do you need (From university you can choose between bus 5 or 6)? ")
if bus != "5" or bus != "6":
    print("The bus you choose does not go through Universita'")
    program()
else:
    if bus == "5":
        print("You can choose between 2 directions: Viganello and Lamone Cadempino")
        way = input("Make your choice for the direction: ")
    else:
        print("You can choose between 2 directions: Lugano Stazione and Cornaredo")
        way = input("Make your choice for the direction: ")
```

The problem is: even if I press `5` or`6`, the program goes in the wrong if-statement (`"The bus you choose does not go..."`). How is it possible? It looks so easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your if-statement condition on this line:

```
if bus != "5" or bus != "6":
```

`bus` will *always* be either not equal to `"5"` or not equal to `"6"`.  You should be using `and`:

```
if bus != "5" and bus != "6":
```

That or you could use `not in`:

```
if bus not in {"5", "6"}:
```

This becomes especially useful if you have many values to test for.

Comment: I think I need to sleep or to move around. Thanks man and sorry for the stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

if statement is always `True`:

```
if bus != "5" or bus != "6"
```

you should replace `or` with `and`